# Unable to Run the git:(master) ls-la code in VCS

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I need to run the `git:(master)ls -la` code in the VSC terminal, but it generates the following error.
Please help me solve the error since I couldn't go to the next step.

Error message generate in VCS:

```
master: The term 'master' is not recognized as a name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.**
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

First, try a CMD teminal instead of the default PowerShell one: you will avoid any cmdlet error.

Second, a normal command would be `ls -la`.
The `git(master)` is probably part of the prompt, to mention your current folder is part of a local Git repository, on the `master` branch.

Make sure `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` is part of your `%PATH%`, considering `ls.exe` is in that folder.